# BME Jobs in Industry: Do you need a PhD or Masters?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

As an incoming Senior, I am currently having the debate that many before me have had: Masters, or PhD?

I'm a biomedical engineering student who wants to get an advanced degree to better position myself for high-end R&D and engineering jobs in industry. From what I've gathered, it seems like a Masters can do the trick, though getting a PhD may put me in an even better position. BME seems to be different than other fields when it comes to advanced degrees. It seems to me that the PhD's have more opportunities than Master's upon graduation in the BME field.

So if I ignore all factors, and want to maximize my chances of doing high-end R&D engineering at a good medical imaging company, it seems that PhD is what I should get.

However, here are some considerations that I have.

1) The time and effort required for a PhD is significant. A PhD in BME takes a longer time than average, and is quite difficult. I don't quite enjoy the idea of entering the workforce at the age of 27.

2) However, PhD's are funded fully, so there appears to be no financial burden/debt (apart from the fact that I won't be earning like my Bachelors/Masters counterparts during my PhD years).

3) PhD programs are harder than Masters programs to get in to. I believe I could get into a top tier university for a Masters program, but not a PhD program.

4) Masters requires less time and effort, and seems to get me qualified for more jobs than a bachelor's.

5) A Masters, however, may not qualify me for the high-end R&D that a PhD might.

6) I may be wrong, but funding for Masters programs is limited. I could obtain significant debt.

Number 6 is a big problem for me. Do Masters students incur debt, or do they generally get enough funding to get by? I read in a lot of top universities that no guaranteed funding is available like there is for PhDs, but TA and RA positions may be available. How common is it for Masters students to get such positions?

If Masters students do get funding, then my plan is to enter into a Masters program (hopefully at a top 15 BME program), and apply for jobs at the end of my degree. If I get good opportunities, I'll take them, otherwise, I might apply for a PhD program. (I am worried about one thing; does this extend the amount of time it'll take for me to begin work? Or can I apply the work I've done in my Masters towards my PhD?).

However, if Masters students do not get enough funding, and I could incur debt, my idea was to apply to PhD program and potentially opt out with a Masters if I can get good job opportunities, or if my PhD is too challenging. How frowned upon is doing this (I would imagine that my advisor couldn't be too pleased)?

Any advice would be appreciated! I want to know if my assumptions are reasonable, and if my plans are reasonable as well!